# How to write this json like format on a txt file using the node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, writefile

### I want this format

```
 1   {"index": {"_id": 0}}
 2   { "age_groups" : ["-KmQN3SH7_ ........100000 words in sinle line
 3   {"index": {"_id": 1}}
 4   { "age_groups" : ["-KmQN3SH7_ ........100000 words in sinle line
 5   {"index": {"_id": 2}}
 6   { "age_groups" : ["-KmQN3SH7_ ........100000 words in sinle line
 7   {"index": {"_id": 3}}
 8   { "age_groups" : ["-KmQN3SH7_ ........100000 words in sinle line
```

### But I get this format after I write the file.

```
{"index": {"_id": 0}}
{ "age_groups" : ["-KmQN3SH7_P73cwZrSmD","-KmQN6Aze7LROyH_cCpP","-"-KmQNKlhHrO0AnnAGybq"],  "needs": ["-Km5n7VJ_X5j2Yj9aG6c","-Km5ncKlPDe8C4nFq6kG"], "categories": ["-KmCtR9mDf_CvwtS3B74","-KmCter6Woj-xM1jPNs4"], "tags": , "title": "Bepanthol - Intensive Κρέμα Προσώπου & Ματιών - 50ml", "code": "113829", "brand": "Bepanthol", "price_bought": "0", "price_sell": "16.05", "weight": "50ml", "description": "<h3><span style="font-size:12px"><strong>Bepanthol</strong></span></h3>
```

Can someone tell me how I can achieve that?

This is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var logger = fs.createWriteStream('./Exports/log1.txt', {
  flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
})

function convertProducts_fs() {



  const selectedFile = document.getElementById('inp_products_fs').files[0];
  const filePath = selectedFile.path;
  const fileToRead = filePath;

  jsonfile.readFile(fileToRead, function(err, data) {

    let counter = 0;
    for (let key in data) {

      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        let element = data[key];
        let SCHEMA = {};

        SCHEMA.age_groups = [];
        SCHEMA.needs = [];
        SCHEMA.categories = [];
        SCHEMA.tags = [];

        SCHEMA.title = element.title;
        SCHEMA.code = element.custom_id;
        SCHEMA.brand = element.brand;
        SCHEMA.price_bought = element.bought_price;
        SCHEMA.price_sell = element.sell_price;
        SCHEMA.weight = element.weight;
        SCHEMA.description = element.description;
        SCHEMA.uses = element.uses;

        SCHEMA.created = element.timestamp;
        SCHEMA.updated = element.timestamp;
        SCHEMA.image_url = '';
        SCHEMA.added_by = 'admin@gmail.com';
        SCHEMA.status = 'inactive';


        for (let _key1 in element.age_groups) {
          SCHEMA.age_groups.push(_key1);
        }

        for (let _key2 in element.needs) {
          SCHEMA.needs.push(_key2);
        }

        for (let _key3 in element.final_category) {
          SCHEMA.categories.push(_key3);
        }


        SCHEMA.created = element.timestamp;
        SCHEMA.updated = element.timestamp;


        let age_groups = JSON.stringify(SCHEMA.age_groups);
        let needs = JSON.stringify(SCHEMA.needs);
        let categories = JSON.stringify(SCHEMA.categories);

        logger.write(`{"index": {"_id": ${counter}}}`) // append string to your file
        logger.write('\r\n')
        logger.write(`{ "age_groups" : ${age_groups},  "needs": ${needs}, "categories": ${categories}, "tags": ${SCHEMA.tags}, "title": "${SCHEMA.title}", "code": "${SCHEMA.code}", "brand": "${SCHEMA.brand}", "price_bought": "${SCHEMA.price_bought}", "price_sell": "${SCHEMA.price_sell}", "weight": "${SCHEMA.weight}", "description": "${SCHEMA.description}", "uses": "${SCHEMA.uses}" }`) // append string to your file
        logger.write('\r\n')
      }

      counter++;


    }

    logger.end();

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly the problems start here:

```
"tags": ${SCHEMA.tags}
```

You aren't passing that value through `JSON.stringify` the way you did with earlier values so it's just getting included unencoded, including all the newline characters within it.

There are then several other similarly unencoded values on that line.

Compare how you output `categories`:

```
let categories = JSON.stringify(SCHEMA.categories);

"categories": ${categories}
```

to how you output `tags`:

```
"tags": ${SCHEMA.tags}
```

All that said, it would be easier to avoid building the JSON in such a piecemeal fashion and just use:

```
logger.write(JSON.stringify(SCHEMA));
```

If you only want to output certain properties you can use:

```
logger.write(JSON.stringify(SCHEMA, ['age_groups', 'needs', /* etc. */]));
```

Comment: My problem is the output because some variables holds html code when i write the file i get break lines but i want to control that

Comment: The updated question doesn't change my answer. Compare how you are handling `categories` to how you are handling `tags`. For `categories` you have passed the value through `JSON.stringify` but you don't do that for `tags`, you just include it unencoded.

Comment: Look the pattern of the output what i want this is the elastic bulk datatype - POST query i just want to convert my data to be able to post data , thta all, The problem is i have html tags inside some variables that break my code, Like <h3> <p>

Comment: The HTML tags are not to blame for splitting the output across multiple lines. Those newline characters appear in your strings and you're squirting them out without JSON encoding them. If you just JSON encode all the values that same way you are for the first 3 values you'll not have any problems with extra lines being inserted.

Comment: OMG OMG Skirtle omg i love you man , i want to cry now, YOU Save me bro , for 72 houers i try to convert that data and you save me omg

Comment: But i have this problem now i thing is easy , i have double quotes on htl tags . like this "description" : ""<h2>Hello worlds </h2>""

Comment: Which of my proposed solutions are you using? If you use the solutions at the end of my answer you shouldn't have a problem with extra quotes. If you want to continue escaping each property individually then you need to remove the quotes that you were including in the string, so `"description": "${SCHEMA.description}"` becomes `"description": ${JSON.stringify(SCHEMA.description)}`. Note how I removed the pairs of `"` around the value.